# Disable "Attach to debugger" Debugger.Launch

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-services

I got a problem, i have accidentally left "Debugger.Launch();" code in my project, which was needed for the debugging as the application is a Windows Service.

Now, i'am done with the projects, it´s working as intended (Mostly) **BUT, every time you start the service, it asks if you want to attach a debugger.**

The Service has been packed to a MSI-package, and is more or less ready for delivery. And the guy who handles all the packaging and such is not at the office and none else know how to do it or has the authority to do it.

Enough with the backstory..

- Can i in any way disable the debugger code without repackaging the
  service? - Or do i have to repackage?
- Is there any startup command or something to prevent it to ask for
  debugger?

I have been searching alot about this, but the most of the existing questions/posts about this regards "Prebuild" solutions, but i'am looking for a "Postbuild" solution.

[EDIT]

Solution (Some kind of..)

I have still no idea if it is even possible to prevent attaching, but with the research i've done, it seems impossible. Therefore i had to recompile the service.

As many of you that commented suggested i implemented a key in the app.config, and a simple "if-case" around the "Debugger.Launch()", which work perfectly. Now i can simply choose to attach debugger or not.

Tamir Vereds solution worked on my local machine, and i did not even try on the customers server, because of the reason he also stated about base my code on this kind of tweaks.

I will accept this answer, as it partly could fix the initial problem.

Thank you all for answering.

Comment: you should modify your app to allow controlling debugging features through `app.config AppSettings`

Comment: @Kilanny what are you talking about? OP is trying to prevent having to rebuild their project.

Comment: @CodeCaster This what I mean. OP has to only modify his code for one time, build one time, then OP can control features by `app.config`

Comment: @Kilanny try reading the question again. OP cannot modify their code.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to prevent some code that has been compiled into binary from running (Unless using some reverse-engineering by patching binary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually I would recommend recompiling the application and allowing it to be invoked with an argument or configuration cancelling the `Debugger.Launch` call, but since you don't want to recompile...

As for the [documentation of `Debugger.Launch()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If a debugger is already attached, nothing happens.

You can take advantage of that fact by making another small process that will "debug" your original process.

Since your process is a windows service you might need to use *Auto-Debugger-Attach*:

- Open the registry editor by typing `regedit` in the `cmd`.
- Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`.
- Add a key with your debugged application's `.exe`'s name.
- Add a string value to that key with the name `Debugger` when the value is your new "Debugger process" path.

With your fake debugger attached, the original process will return frm the `Debugger.Launch` method without invoking another debugger.

Also you might want your fake debugger to deattach itself somehow later on so you can still really debug your application when needed.

***Note that this is sort of an tweak and you don't want to base your production code on this kind of stuff.***

Comment: Hmm, nobody that knows how to write a debugger is in the office.

Comment: You don't really need your fake debugger to be functional, just to attach as one so the `Debugger.Launch` will see it. Anyway, as I said, I would recommend to just recompile the code with the desired changes.